# how to collide objects in corona labs

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to make a game in Corona SDK where a player runs and survives through obstacles by either jumping over them or killing them using bullets. The problem is that the game ends even if the player fires the bullet. But it should be over only if the player collides with the obstacles.
This is my code till now!!

```
--local screen_adjustment = 1
local physics = require "physics" 
physics.start()

local storyboard = require ("storyboard")
local scene = storyboard.newScene()


function scene:createScene( event )

local screenGroup=self.view

background=display.newImage("rsz_islands1-background-animation.png")
background:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
background.x=-50
background.y=330
background.speed=math.random(2,6)
screenGroup:insert(background)

background1=display.newImage("rsz_islands1-background-animation.png")
background1:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
background1.x=500
background1.y=330
background1.speed=math.random(2,6)
screenGroup:insert(background1)

rightArrow=display.newImageRect("right_arrow.png",50,100)
rightArrow:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
rightArrow.x=370
rightArrow.y=290
screenGroup:insert(rightArrow)


upArrow=display.newImageRect("up_Arrow.png",100,50)
upArrow:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
upArrow.x=250
upArrow.y=240
screenGroup:insert(upArrow)



stone=display.newImageRect("stone.png",100,50)
stone:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
stone.x=math.random(500,1500)
stone.y=280
stone.speed=math.random(2,6)
physics.addBody(stone,"static",{bounce=0,friction=0,})
screenGroup:insert(stone)

base = display.newRect(0,0,450,3)
base.x=-50
base.y=282
base:setReferencePoint(display.BottomLeftReferencePoint)
base:setFillColor(255,255,255)
--physics.addBody(base,"static",{bounce=0.1,friction=0.1})
physics.addBody(base,"static",{bounce=0,friction=1.0,density=1.0})
screenGroup:insert(base)
base.myName="base1"


local sheetData = {
width=65,
height=75,
numFrames=4,
sheetContentWidth=130,
sheetContentHeight=150
}

local mySprite = graphics.newImageSheet("imageSheet.png",sheetData)

local sequenceData = {
name="normalRun",
frames={1,2,3,4},
time=500,
loopcount=0
}

animation = display.newSprite(mySprite,sequenceData)
if(animation.x<50) then
animation.x=50
end
animation.y=245


physics.addBody(animation,{bounce=0.3,friction=1.0,density=1.0,radius=35})
animation:play()
screenGroup:insert(animation)
animation.myName="animation1"




local sheetTigerData = {
width=100,
height=57,
numFrames=8,
sheetContentWidth=400,
sheetContentHeight=120
}

local myTigerSprite
graphics.newImageSheet("tigerImageSheet.png",sheetTigerData)

local sequenceTigerData = {
name="normalRun",
frames={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
time=500,
loopcount=0
}

tigeranimation = display.newSprite(myTigerSprite,sequenceTigerData)
--tigeranimation.x=700
tigeranimation.x=math.random(500,1500)
tigeranimation.y=255
tigeranimation.speed=math.random(2,6)
physics.addBody(tigeranimation,"static",{bounce=0,friction=.2})
tigeranimation:play()
screenGroup:insert(tigeranimation)


local sheetBirdData = {
width=60,
height=40,
numFrames=6,
sheetContentWidth=180,
sheetContentHeight=80
}

local myBirdSprite =
graphics.newImageSheet("birdimagesheet.png",sheetBirdData)

local sequenceBirdData = {
name="normalRun",
frames={1,2,3,4,5,6},
time=500,
loopcount=0
}

birdanimation = display.newSprite(myBirdSprite,sequenceBirdData)
birdanimation.x=math.random(500,2500)
birdanimation.y=math.random(100,200)
birdanimation.speed=2
birdanimation.initY=birdanimation.y
birdanimation.amp=50
birdanimation.angle=math.random(1,360)
physics.addBody(birdanimation,"static",{friction=.2,bounce=0})
birdanimation:play()
screenGroup:insert(birdanimation)

local sheetCatData = {
width=100,
height=48,
numFrames=8,
sheetContentWidth=200,
sheetContentHeight=200
}

local myCatSprite =  
graphics.newImageSheet("rsz_runningcat.png",sheetCatData)

local sequenceCatData = {
name="normalRun",
frames={2,1,4,3,6,5,8,7},
time=500,
loopcount=0
}

catanimation = display.newSprite(myCatSprite,sequenceCatData)
catanimation.x=tigeranimation.x+math.random(110,1500)
catanimation.y=255
catanimation.speed=math.random(2,6)
physics.addBody(catanimation,"static",{bounce=0,friction=.2})
catanimation:play()
screenGroup:insert(catanimation)



gameSound=audio.loadStream("gamesound.mp3")
audio.play(gameSound)

gunshot=audio.loadStream("gunshot3.mp3")
end


function scrollBack( self,event )
if self.x<-590 then
self.x=500
audio.play(gameSound)
else 
    self.x=self.x-3
    audio.play(gameSound)
end
end

function moveTiger( self,event )
if self.x<-100 then
self.x=math.random(1500,4000)
self.y=255
self.speed=math.random(3,6)
audio.play(gameSound)
else 
    self.x=self.x-self.speed
    audio.play(gameSound)
end
end

function moveCat( self,event )
if self.x<-100 then
self.x=tigeranimation.x+math.random(800,2000)
self.y=255
self.speed=math.random(3,6)
else 
    self.x=self.x-self.speed
end
end


function moveStone( self,event )
if self.x<-100 then
self.x=math.random(1000,5000)
self.y=280
self.speed=math.random(3,6)
else 
    self.x=self.x-self.speed
end
end

function moveBird( self,event )
if self.x<-100 then
self.x=math.random(500,2500)
--self.x=300
self.y=math.random(100,200)
self.speed=2
self.amp=math.random(25,75)
self.angle=math.random(1,360)
--self.y=280
--self.speed=math.random(3,6)
else 
    self.x=self.x-self.speed
    self.angle=self.angle+.1
    self.y=self.amp*math.sin(self.angle)+self.initY
end
end

function fireLasers()
 blaster = display.newImageRect( "bullet.png", 40, 15 )
 physics.addBody(blaster,"dynamic")
blaster.x = animation.x+50
blaster.y = animation.y-10
--blaster.collided=false
if(animation.x<50) then
animation.x=50
end
transition.to( blaster, { time=1000, x=500} )
audio.play(gunshot)

end


function handleFireButton( event )
if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
    -- Fire the weapon
    fireLasers()
elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
    -- Stop firing the weapon
    fireLasers()
end
return true
end
positionInAir = false

function jump(event)
if(event.phase == "began" and positionInAir==false) then

    --playerInAir = true
    --animation:setLinearVelocity( 0, 1 )
    animation:applyForce(0,-1000,animation.x,animation.y)
    positionInAir=true
    --physics.addBody(animation,"dynamic")
    --print("touch")
end
return true
end




function onCollision( event )
if(event.object1.myName == "base1" and event.object2.myName == "animation1")    
then
    positionInAir = false;
    -- base:removeSelf()
end
end

local function onManCollide(event)

if ( event.phase == "began"  ) then
storyboard.gotoScene("restart","fade",400)
audio.stop()
end
end




function scene:enterScene( event )

background.enterFrame=scrollBack
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",background)

background1.enterFrame=scrollBack
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",background1)

stone.enterFrame=moveStone
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",stone)

tigeranimation.enterFrame=moveTiger
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",tigeranimation)

birdanimation.enterFrame=moveBird
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",birdanimation)

catanimation.enterFrame=moveCat
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",catanimation)

animation.collision=onManCollide
animation:addEventListener("collision",onManCollide)


rightArrow:addEventListener( "touch", handleFireButton )
--Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", handleFireButton )
--Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", handleFireButton )
--upArrow:addEventListener("touch", jump)

--Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision ) 
--Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", onScreenTouch )

--rightArrow:addEventListener( "touch", handleFireButton )
end


function scene:exitScene( event )

Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",background)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",background1)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",stone)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",tigeranimation)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",birdanimation)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",catanimation)
Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame",onManCollide)
rightArrow:removeEventListener( "touch", handleFireButton )
upArrow:removeEventListener("touch", jump)
Runtime:removeEventListener( "collision", onCollision )


end

function scene:destroyScene( event )

end
--local myGroup=display.newGroup()

--physics.addBody(background,"static",{bounce=0.1,friction=0.9})


--physics.addBody(background1,"static",{ bounce=0.1,friction=0.9})

scene:addEventListener("createScene",scene)
scene:addEventListener("enterScene",scene)
scene:addEventListener("exitScene",scene)
scene:addEventListener("destroyScene",scene)

return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask a specific question, what you have said is quite vague. Does the game end each time the player fires the bullet? Also you should consider migrating from storyboard to composer.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration.. Yes as soon as the player fires the bullet the game ends!